# How do I calculate the adjusted percentage of dice out comes.

Tags: probability, dice, percentages

What I’m attempting to do is construct a spreadsheet to calculate the number of wounds and kills for a tabletop board game I play. To give everyone an idea of the situation. You have figure A shoots at figure B. In this situation you have the “percentage for figure A to Hit figure B” the percentage for figure A to Wound figure B ” the “percentage for figure B to Fail an Armor Save ”. This is all bases on a D6 die and sometimes multiple D6 rolls.

I have in my spreadsheet already been able to calculate the percentage of “The Percentage to HIT”, “Percentage To wound” and the “Percentage to Fail an Armor Save”.

Now my issue is where (in the game) the weapon used to wound on a roll of 6 on a six sided roll there is no save possible.

Example: Figure A shoots at figure B and “The Percentage to HIT” is 89%. The Percentage of figure A to wound figure B is 33%. The percentage of Figure B to “fail the Armor Save” is 17%. Now add in the case were on a roll of a 6 on six sided die there is no save possible.

In the end I’m attempting to figure how many wounds Figure B is going to suffer.

A couple of questions

1. Do I calculate the 1/6 chance off the percentage of figure A to wound figure B? So off the 33%. 
   So in this example the “To wound percentage” is figured as 5+ so a 2/6 thus .3333 = 33%. In that case is it 1/2 = .5000 thus 50%.
2. Once I calculate the percentage of the 1/6, where in my calculations should I add that. =SUM(To_hit_% x To_Wound_% x Fail_save_%)

Do I add it to the Fail_save_percentage or the To_wound_percentage.

As you can see it is a bit of a complex question. But at the root it seems pretty simple.

Comment: Do you want the possibility to roll a 1 or 6 on a 6 sided die?

Comment: Well the concept is for a game. I need to calculate the percentage to fail the a saving throw. Which is on a 2+ the character saves and is not hurt. So the percentage to Fail save is 1 in 6 on a six sided die. so 1/6 or .1667 or 17%.

Comment: Well the concept is for a game. I need to calculate the percentage to fail the a saving throw. Which is on a 2+ the character saves and is not hurt. So the percentage to Fail save is 1 in 6 on a six sided die. so 1/6 or .1667 or 17%. 
The weapon being used to hurt the character has a ability to not allow a saving throw on a roll of 6 on a six sided die. Which is a 1/6 or .1667 or 17%. 
So I assume that in 1/6 time the weapon will not allow the saving throw needs to be appended to the 1/6 chance the character has to Fail the saving throw. 
I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: This is a rather easy question to answer if you know which game you're speaking about (I think it's Warhammer, though). Most probably you'd get a better answer in BoardGames.SE

Comment: It is 40k that I am speaking of.

Answer (score 0):

Rending?

You would add it to the failed save, since the save does (auto-)fail, so the probability of a failed save per wound dice roll is 1/6 (.16) + (% to wound * % chance to fail save).

For the total wounds applied it's going to be (%chance_to_hit * (1/6+(%chance to wound * % chance to fail save)) * # of dice.